# db.createUser is not creating any user in mongodb in docker setup

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am building a mongodb image in docker and in one of the startup shell script I am creating two mongodb users as below.

```
mongod --dbpath /data/db &

RET=1
while [[ RET -ne 0 ]]; do
    echo "=> Waiting for confirmation of MongoDB service startup"
    sleep 5
    mongo admin --eval "help" >/dev/null 2>&1
    RET=$?
done

ADMINUSER=rootUser
ADMINPASS=changeMe
DBUSER=opal
DBPASSWORD=opal

mongo admin --eval "db.createUser({user: '$ADMINUSER', pwd: '$ADMINPASS', roles:[{role:'root',db:'admin'}]});"

mongo opaldb --eval "db.createUser({user: '$DBUSER', pwd: '$DBPASSWORD', roles:[{role:'dbOwner',db:'opaldb'}]});"

mongod --shutdown
```

After opening the mongodb container I can only see the admin user and not the other user.

```
> use admin
switched to db admin
> show users
{
        "_id" : "admin.rootUser",
        "user" : "rootUser",
        "db" : "admin",
        "roles" : [
                {
                        "role" : "root",
                        "db" : "admin"
                }
        ]
}
> use opald
switched to db opald
> show users
>
```

Am I missing something stupid?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "I can only see the admin user and not the other user"? Which commands / shell helpers do you use?

Comment: @OriDar When I connect to mongo shell and run show users I can only see the rootsUser created and not the second one. I have edited my question.

Comment: is that a typo use opald vs use opaldb ?

Comment: @Veeram its just a typo

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the first user then you need to authenticate and then create the second user

```
mongo admin --eval "db.auth('${admin_user}','${admin_password}');db.createUser({user: '$DBUSER', pwd: '$DBPASSWORD', roles:[{role:'dbOwner',db:'opaldb'}]});"
```